# How can I access the child nodes? DOM XML

Tags: xml, dom, autohotkey

How can I get the value/text of the child-node "description" and "created-at"?
I have had this working before a year ago but now I can't get it to work again. Please help.

```
    xmlPath := "C:\Script\doc.xml"
    xmlDoc := ComObjCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xmlDoc.async := false
    xmlDoc.load(xmlPath)


    for item in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ticket") {
        string := item.text
        stringDesc := item.getAttribute("description").text
        stringTime := item.getAttribute("created-at").text

        FileAppend, %string%, C:\Script\htmlversion.html
        FileAppend, %stringDesc%, C:\Script\htmlversion.html
        FileAppend, %stringTime%, C:\Script\htmlversion.html
    }




    XML:
    <ticket>
    <id type="integer">31</id>
    <description> This is some text I want to access. </description>
    <created-at type="dateTime">2018-02-14T11:27:52+01:00</created-at>
    </ticket>
```

The first one works:

```
    string := item.text
```

But not the other two:

```
    stringDesc := item.getAttribute("description").text
    stringTime := item.getAttribute("created-at").text
```

Answer (score 0):

`description` and `created-at` aren't attribute in your example case.

You should try:

```
for item in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ticket") {
    string := item.text
}

for item in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description") {
    stringDesc := item.text
}

for item in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("created-at") {
    stringTime := item.text
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcon. The problem with this approach is that it will first generate all descriptions, and Then the created-at dates. I want to go through one ticket-node's child-nodes, and then move on to the next ticket node.